# css transitions - animation doesn't work properly at start

Tags: jquery, css-transitions

I maked an animation controlled by two `buttons` for move vertically a `div`,
using jquery `click`, but the problem is that the animation doesn't work properly at start..

CSS

```
.black-div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    transition: top 1s 0s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1);
}
```

JS

```
$(".button-up").click(function(){
        $(".black-div").css({"top":"0px"});
});

$(".button-down").click(function(){
        $(".black-div").css({"top":"300px"});
});
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/B6t2D/

Comment: Your code should be in your question. Also, "*doesn't work properly"* is a terrible problem description. How about *"when I first click, the div jumps without smoothly transitioning"*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You aren't providing an initial state to *transition* from. Add this to your CSS `.black-div` selector...

```
top: 0;
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/B6t2D/3/

Comment: Wow 3 years later i find myself here. Thank you!